# Laravel Passport Multiauth

Tags: php, laravel, api, laravel-5.4, laravel-passport

I am working on an API for 2 frontend apps (vue2/mobile). One uses `User` model and the other uses the `Admin` model (Laravel is just an API)

I am using `Laravel Passport` for authenticating users and admins, i successfully provided access token for users but i'm facing some problem with admins

So for i did

1-> created `Admin` model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class Admin extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password','role',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
}
```

2-> created a admins guard which uses passport

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'passport',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
    'admin' => [
        'driver' => 'passport',
        'provider' => 'admins',
    ],
],
```

3-> created Route and Controller for granting access token for admins

```
Route::post('/oauth/token/admin', [
    'uses' => 'Auth\CustomAccessTokenController@issueUserToken'
]);

<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface;
use Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\AccessTokenController;

class CustomAccessTokenController extends AccessTokenController
{
    /**
     * Hooks in before the AccessTokenController issues a token
     *
     *
     * @param  ServerRequestInterface $request
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function issueUserToken(ServerRequestInterface $request)
    {
        $httpRequest = request();

        if ($httpRequest->grant_type == 'password') {

            $admin = \App\Admin::where('email', $httpRequest->username)
                               ->where('password', $httpRequest->password)
                               ->first();
            //dd($admin);

            return $this->issueToken($request);
        }
    }
}
```

4-> i tested with Postman

```
http://localhost:8000/api/oauth/token/admin

client_id:4
client_secret:M4QkLqhPkJ4pGL52429RipassQ3BOjKTJZe3uoWK
grant_type:password
username:admin@gmail.com
password:secret

//i'm getting
{
  "error": "invalid_credentials",
  "message": "The user credentials were incorrect."
}

//if i use the User model credentials 
username:user@gmail.com
password:secret

//i'm getting the access token 
{
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "expires_in": 31536000,
  "access_token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1Qi....",
  "refresh_token": "UI354EfJlVdmOhO...."
}
```

i'm really tired figuring out what went wrong

looking forward for much needed help

thank you

Comment: are you using any admin middle ware ?

Comment: @rajatsaurastri thank you for your time, no i'm not using any middleware i just want to grant access token for `admin guard` and log them in

Comment: so you are getting 401 error code ?

Comment: @rajatsaurastri   yes exactly, is there any way to achieve this, can you please point me in right direction

Comment: in your case, while generating access toke for admin it will hit the api guard and will try to call user access to authenticate. Since admin is not present in the user it will throw 401. So in your controller where you are generating access for user, check whether user is admin if so write your logic to generate access for admin

Comment: @rajatsaurastri  that seems my problem, i was referring to https://github.com/laravel/passport/issues/161, but coudn't get through, can you please post some code how to do that, please

Comment: This is going to be tricky as laravel passport doesn't use multi guard.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/140074/discussion-between-mr-robot-and-rajatsaurastri).